# How should I batch query an append-only table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

Suppose I have an append-only table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `states` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`person_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

);

There is an index on `name` and another on `person_id` (`person_id` is a fkey reference to another table).

For each name, we store a mapping to `person_id` for a given date range. The mapping from `name` -> `person_id` is many to one (this is a contrived example, but think of it as storing how a person could change their name). We never want to delete history so when altering the mapping, we insert a new entry. The last entry for a given name is the source of truth. We end up wanting to ask two different types of questions on the dataset, for which I have some general questions.

1. What is the current mapping for a given name/list of names?

If there is only one name, the most straightforward query is:

```
select * from states where name = 'name' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If there is more than one name, the best way I could figure out is to do:

```
select * from states as a 
    left join states as b on a.name = b.name and a.id < b.id
where isnull(b.id);
```

Is this actually the best way to batch query? For a batch of 1, how much worse would the second query be than the first? Using explain, I can tell we end up doing two index lookups instead of 1. Given we care a lot about the performance of this individual lookup, my gut is to run different queries depending on the number of names we are querying for. I'd prefer if there was a way to defer to mysql's optimizer though. Is there a way to write this query so mysql figures out what to do for me?

2. What are the current mappings that map to `person_id` / a list of `person_id`s?

The way I would query for that is:

```
select * from states as a 
    left join states as b on a.name = b.name and a.id < b.id
where isnull(b.id) and person_id in person_id_list
```

I am slightly concerned about the performance for small lists though because my understanding of how mysql works is limited. Using explain, I know that mysql filters by person_id via the index on a before filtering by isnull(b.id). But does it do this before the join or after the join? Could we end up wasting a lot of time joining these two tables? How could I figure this out in general?

Comment: I'd look at using [MariaDB system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/) resulting in the same query for #1 and a very simple query for #2 (per documentation).

Answer (score 0):

The code in (1) is "groupwise-max", but done in a very inefficient way.  (Follow the tag I added for more discussion.)

May I suggest you have two tables; one that is append-only, like you have.  Let's call this table `History`.  Then have another table called `Current`.  When you add a new entry, `INSERT` into `History`, but replace into `Current`.

If you do take this approach, consider what differences you might have in the two tables.  The `PRIMARY KEY` will certainly be different; other indexes may be different, and even some columns may be different.